# How to compare strings in my case (android)

Tags: android, string, equals

I have two string that i get them with this code

```
final String encrypted_id = encryption.encryptOrNull(android_id);
final String preLoad = preferences.getString("pur", "no");
```

for make sure that they are equal i Log them like this

```
Log.d("encrypted_id",encrypted_id);
Log.d("preferences.getString",preferences.getString("pur", "no"));
```

and LogCat output is like this

```
         D/encrypted_id﹕ wxgNDxqzNWNgYWrE0fxjaU07a54XBFnAToy56MAV1Y0=
D/preferences.getString﹕ wxgNDxqzNWNgYWrE0fxjaU07a54XBFnAToy56MAV1Y0=
```

so I make sure that they are equal

**NOW** i want to compare them like this

```
if(preLoad.equals(encrypted_id))
    {
        Log.d("app","is premium");

    }
    else {
        Log.d("app","is not premium");
    }
```

**BUT** LogCat show this to me

```
D/app﹕ is not premium
```

What's the problem ?

PS: I tried

`1 . preLoad.equalsIgnoreCase(encrypted_id)`

`2 . preLoad.compareTo(encrypted_id)==0`

Comment: did you try preLoad.trim().equals(encrypted_id.trim()) ???

Comment: can you print `encrypted_id` and `preLoad` inside the else ?

Comment: use equalignore case and also trim() and then check

Comment: I wonder what happens if you compare `preLoad.equals("wxgNDxqzNWNgYWrE0fxjaU07a54XBFnAToy56MAV1Y0=")` and `encrypted_id.equals("wxgNDxqzNWNgYWrE0fxjaU07a54XBFnAToy56MAV1Y0=")`

Comment: I believe there are white character as others mentioned :)

Comment: @user3676184 equalignore is not necessary on his code, id must be unique

Comment: @StefanBeike Thanks . You are right the problem solved by add .trim()

Comment: @behrooz glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
if(preLoad.equals(encrypted_id))
    {
        Log.d("app","is premium");

    }
    else {
        Log.d("app","is not premium");
    }
```

to

```
if(preLoad.trim().equals(encrypted_id.trim()))
    {
        Log.d("app","is premium");

    }
    else {
        Log.d("app","is not premium");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(stringsCompare(preLoad.trim(),encrypted_id.trim()))
    {
        Log.d("app","is premium");

    }
    else {
        Log.d("app","is not premium");
    }
```

stringsCompare is a procedure that I wrote for string comparison:

```
    public boolean stringsCompare(String firstString, String secondString){
            if(firstString.length() != secondString.length()){
                //The length of the two strings are not equal
                return false;
            }else{
                for(int i = 0; i < firstString.length(); i++)
                {
                    if (firstString.charAt(i) != secondString.charAt(i))
                    {
                        //Let's log the difference:
                        Log.d("app","Difference at char: "+i+" its value in the first string is: "+firstString.charAt(i)+" and its value in the first string is: "+secondString.charAt(i));
                        //The strings are not equal
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                //All characters were equal
                return true;
            }
}
```

In this case you can see the difference if there is any.

Comment: thank you . but i think use equals and trim is much easier .

Comment: No problem, you can have it as an extra answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
if(!preLoad.trim().equals(encrypted_id.trim()))
{
    Log.d("app","is not premium");

}
else {
    Log.d("app","is premium");
}
```